# "Command not found" error in shell script]

Tags: shell

```
while read merchant_id address1 address2 city state postal_code code name

do

echo `mysqal -uxxxx -hxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx merchant_staging -e 
"select id from pickup_locations where merchant_id ='$merchant_id' and address1 = '$address1' and postal_code = '$postal_code' and name = '$name'"| grep -v id` >> mer1
echo ":" >>mer1 

done < merchantadd.txt
```

Comment: `mysqal`? Surely you meant `mysql`.

Comment: got it i have i identified this error and exiguting the script its working

Answer (score 0):

```
while read merchant_id address1 address2 city state postal_code code name
do

echo `mysql -uxxx -hxxxxxxxxxxx merchant_staging -e "select id from pickup_locations where merchant_id ='$merchant_id' and address1 = '$address1' and postal_code = '$postal_code' and name = '$name'" | grep -v id` >> mer1
echo ":" >>mer1

done < merchantadd.txt

read m1 < mer1
while read code
echo `mysql -uxxx -hxxxxxxxxxx facilities -e 
"insert into service_areas (type,type_id,value,code,active,updated_at,created_at) values ('pickupLocationMapping','$m1','pickupLocationMapping','$code',1,now(),now());"`
echo "No:of row's requested in Service_areas got created"

done < vendorpc.txt
```

Comment: while writing this am getting erroe as un

Comment: /facilitycreation.sh: line 56: ech: command not found
./facilitycreation.sh: line 68: syntax error near unexpected token `done'
./facilitycreation.sh: line 68: `done < vendorpc.txt'

Comment: Would you please reformat your code so that it can be read properly?

Comment: This looks like an extension to the question, and not the answer.

Comment: (My report that this is 'not an answer' has been disputed. I think the comments give it away, but I'll leave it be now).